# Showing that if $\varphi \circ f$ is integrable over $[0,1]$ whenever $f$ is, then there are constants $c_1$ and $c_2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory

For those who have read Royden & Fitzpatrick, Real Analysis 4 edition. In Problem 71, page 134, there is a problem for which I am unsure how to reference and prove because I am unable to find a (45), has anyone else experienced this?

Let $\varphi$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}.$ Show that if there are constants for which (45) holds, then $\varphi\circ f$ is integrable over $[0,1]$ whenever $f$ is. Then show that if $\varphi \circ f$ is integrable over $[0,1]$ whenever $f$ is, then there are constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ for which (45) holds.

Comment: Without looking into the book: My guess would be $|\varphi(t)| \leq c_1 |t| + c_2$ for (45).

Comment: @supinf thank you, my guess was the same except $|t|$ was next to $c_2$ but i do not think it matters

Answer (score 2):

See the [errata](http://www2.math.umd.edu/%7Epmf/docs/Real%20Analysis.pdf): Refer to equation (43), not (45).

Comment: Thank you so much! Helps a lot